# Win8 C# - UDP listener and thread stop

Tags: c#, .net, udp, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm having problem with Win8 metro application written in C#. I have UDP listener which receives packets (simple one string command) from WP7 device.

I can see that packets are getting to app, but I can only receive couple of them. After some time (5-10 sec) in output window I receive

> The thread 0x5a4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I don't understand why thread stops. This is my source code, which is quite simple. I binded listener, setup event handler and then when I receive command I just move Ellipse shape (user) on UI.

Code :

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DatagramSocket listener = new DatagramSocket();          
    listener.MessageReceived += listener_MessageReceived;            

    try
    {
        await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(serviceName.Text);            
    }
    catch (Exception exception)          
    {               
        if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
        {
            throw;
        }                
    }                
}

async void listener_MessageReceived(DatagramSocket socket, DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs eventArguments)
{
    try
    {
        uint stringLength = eventArguments.GetDataReader().UnconsumedBufferLength;
        string command = eventArguments.GetDataReader().ReadString(stringLength);

        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                MessageBlock.Text = "Message : " + command + " (@ " + DateTime.Now;
                MakeMove(command); 
            }
        );            
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        SocketErrorStatus socketError = SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult);
        if (socketError == SocketErrorStatus.ConnectionResetByPeer)
        {                     
            Debug.WriteLine("Peer does not listen on the specific port. Please make sure that you run step 1 first " +
                        "or you have a server properly working on a remote server."); 
        }
        else if (socketError != SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error happened when receiving a datagram: " + socketError.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}

private void MakeMove(string command)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(command);

    switch (command)
    {
        case "10":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) - 50);
            break;
        case "20":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + 50);
            break;
        case "30":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + 50);
            break;
        case "40":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) - 50);
            break;
        case "50":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + 50);
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) - 50);
            break;
        case "60":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) - 50);
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) - 50);
            break;
        case "70":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + 50);
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + 50);
            break;
        case "80":
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) - 50);
            this.user.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Convert.ToInt32(this.user.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + 50);
            break;
        default:
            Debug.WriteLine("Unknown command");
            break;
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you calling `Dispatcher.RunAsync`?

Comment: Because I'm getting error "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread." without it. It's equivalent of Dispatcher.Begin in Silverlight

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem?